React conditional rendering and smooth animations/transitions
What is the proper/most efficient way to achieve smooth animation with conditional rendering a component in React? I read on other posts that one of the ways to achieve this is to have a state and set it to false on the end of animation/transition using onAnimationEnd and onTransitionEnd like in the following example:
const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(true);
const divRef = useRef(null);

return(
   <>
      {isEnabled && <div onAnimationEnd={(e) => {if (e.animationName === 'closeDivAnim') setIsEnabled(false)}} isactive={isEnabled.toString()}></div>}
      <button onClick={() => divRef.current.setAttribute('isactive', 'false')}>Close div</button>
   </>
)

But to me, that seems like an unreliable approach (correct me if i'm wrong). Another approach which seemed more reliable to me was to follow the same concept but to set the state using a setTimeOut with the duration of the animation in a useEffect hook. All these approaches "get the job done" but what is the propper way to achieve a smooth mount/unmount of a component.
I am new to React so any intel would be highly appreciated!

You can use Suspense tag give it a fallback value so whenever component unmounts inside the suspense tag it will show loading or ui which you passed in to fallback,
or you can also use useTransition hook if you are using function components. Please refer official docs for more info about these elements
